# JS_EvaluateScript with scope chain

Tags: c++, c, spidermonkey, jsapi

I saw example code on spider monkey site , JS_EvaluateScript always refer to global scope object , 
If I would like to create scope object which the parent is global scope , this will work ?

```
JS_EvaluateScript (cx , scope_obj, ... )
```

scope_1 ----has -- global object as parent
scope_2 ----has -- global object as parent as well

**When I run**

```
  JS_EvaluateScript(cx , scope_1 , "var scope1var = 'hello'"....)
```

it's fine...

**And Then I run**

```
  JS_EvaluateScript(cx , scope_2 , "scope1var +' world'"....)
```

it should has error because scope_2 doesn't have variable of scope_1.

**but the result return as " hello world"**

Please advise if I miss anything , sir

============================

Or could you please tell me how to implement when code is entering new scope ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I found script with "var" snytax , the JS_EvaluateScript function will execute with global scope only

JS_EvaluateScript(cx , scope_1 , "var scope1var = 'hello'"....)

it declare variable as global scope / or just like run define Property of global scope with JSPROP_PERMANENT flag (so you can not run script "delete scope1var" )

JS_DefineProperty(cx,globalScop,...,JSPROP_PERMANENT)